# x.classList.toggle() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css

So I have this script that is a counter that follows an infinite animation. The counter resets to 0 everytime an interation finishes. On the line fourth from the bottom I am trying to invoke a x.classList.toggle() to change css when the counter hits 20. When I replace the classList.toggle with an alert() function it works, but as is no class 'doton' is added to 'dot1'. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/8TVn5/

```
window.onload = function () {

var currentPercent = 0;

var showPercent = window.setInterval(function() {

    $('#dot1').on('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration     MSAnimationIteration', function (e) {
  currentPercent= 0;}); 



   if (currentPercent < 100) {
   currentPercent += 1;
  } else {
    currentPercent = 0;
 }

   if (currentPercent == 20){document.getElementByID('dot1').classList.toggle('doton');}
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentPercent;
}, 200);


};
```

Comment: try .toggleClass('doton');

Answer (score 1):

I't just a typo: its should be `getElementById`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8TVn5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing jQuery and normal selectors?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var currentPercent = 0,
        dot1 = $('#dot1');
    var showPercent = window.setInterval(function() {
        dot1.on('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration  MSAnimationIteration',
            function (e) {
                currentPercent= 0;
            }
        ); 

        if (currentPercent < 100) {
            currentPercent += 1;
        } else {
            currentPercent = 0;
        }

        if (currentPercent === 20){
            dot1.toggleClass('doton');
        }
        $('#result').html(currentPercent);

    }, 200);
};
```

Comment: This code is a bit of a paste-job that I've been working on to learn javascript. What is the issue with doing so?

Comment: it's not an issue per-say, but it's better to stick to the framework you're using to avoid browser compatibility issues.

Comment: on that note, is there a simple way to watch animationiteration without Jquery?